# How to convert standard timedelta string to timedelta object

Tags: python, datetime

What is the simplest way to convert standard timedelta string to timedelta object?

I have printed several timedelta objects and got these strings:

```
'1157 days, 9:46:39'
'12:00:01.824952'
'-1 day, 23:59:31.859767'
```

I know I could write parser myself, but is there any simpler solution?

Comment: Bigger picture: why are you trying to round-trip object > string > object?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I need to use API which returns timedelta object as string.

Comment: Same as @jonrsharpe - what have you got this situation. The most straight forward way to round-trip a timedelta is `seconds = timedelta_obj.total_seconds()` then `timedelta_obj = timedelta(seconds=seconds)`...

Comment: Wow... that's a ridiculous response for an API to make. Anyway, there's no builtin Python method. So, you're after writing your own, or looking on pypi/github/etc... to see if anyone's already done it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I cannot find a better way other than writing a parser myself. The code looks bulky but it is essentially parsing string into a dictionary which is useful not only to creating a timedelta object.

```
import re

def parse(s):
    if 'day' in s:
        m = re.match(r'(?P<days>[-\d]+) day[s]*, (?P<hours>\d+):(?P<minutes>\d+):(?P<seconds>\d[\.\d+]*)', s)
    else:
        m = re.match(r'(?P<hours>\d+):(?P<minutes>\d+):(?P<seconds>\d[\.\d+]*)', s)
    return {key: float(val) for key, val in m.groupdict().iteritems()}
```

Test:

```
from datetime import timedelta

s1 = '1157 days, 9:46:39'
s2 = '12:00:01.824952'
s3 = '-1 day, 23:59:31.859767'
t1 = parse(s1)
t2 = parse(s2)
t3 = parse(s3)

timedelta(**t1) # datetime.timedelta(1157, 35199)
timedelta(**t2) # datetime.timedelta(0, 43201, 824952)
timedelta(**t3) # datetime.timedelta(-1, 86371, 859767)
```

Hope this can suit your purpose.

Comment: NOTE: You can change iteritems() to items() and this will work in Python 3

Answer (score 2):

This is an update of Ray's answer that works for Python 3. It will return an empty string if the regex is fed a bad string for parsing, otherwise a timedelta object is returned.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import re

def parse_timedelta(stamp):
    if 'day' in stamp:
        m = re.match(r'(?P<d>[-\d]+) day[s]*, (?P<h>\d+):'
                     r'(?P<m>\d+):(?P<s>\d[\.\d+]*)', stamp)
    else:
        m = re.match(r'(?P<h>\d+):(?P<m>\d+):'
                     r'(?P<s>\d[\.\d+]*)', stamp)
    if not m:
        return ''

    time_dict = {key: float(val) for key, val in m.groupdict().items()}
    if 'd' in time_dict:
        return timedelta(days=time_dict['d'], hours=time_dict['h'],
                         minutes=time_dict['m'], seconds=time_dict['s'])
    else:
        return timedelta(hours=time_dict['h'],
                         minutes=time_dict['m'], seconds=time_dict['s'])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Django, you could do

```py
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_duration
parse_duration('-1 day, 23:59:31.859767')
```

Comment: Great! See [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/718b32c6918037cfc746d7867333d79a3c887a8c/django/utils/dateparse.py#L132).