# Turn a string back into a datetime timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

A column in my pandas data frame represents a time delta that I calculated with datetime then exported into a csv and read back into a pandas data frame. Now the column's dtype is object whereas I want it to be a timedelta so I can perform a groupby function on the dataframe. Below is what the strings look like. Thanks!

```
  0 days 00:00:57.416000
  0 days 00:00:12.036000
  0 days 16:46:23.127000  
 49 days 00:09:30.813000  
 50 days 00:39:31.306000  
 55 days 12:39:32.269000
-1 days +22:03:05.256000
```

Update, my best attempt at writing a for-loop to iterate over a specific column in my pandas dataframe:

```
def delta(i):
    days, timestamp = i.split(" days ")
    timestamp = timestamp[:len(timestamp)-7]
    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp,"%H:%M:%S") + 
    datetime.timedelta(days=int(days))
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=t.day, hours=t.hour, 
    minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)
    delta.total_seconds()

data['diff'].map(delta)
```

Comment: Do you want to have the timedelta in seconds?

Comment: Ideally they would be!

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21074100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pd.to_timedelta`

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.iloc[:, 0])

0     0 days 00:00:57.416000
1     0 days 00:00:12.036000
2     0 days 16:46:23.127000
3    49 days 00:09:30.813000
4    50 days 00:39:31.306000
5    55 days 12:39:32.269000
6   -1 days +22:03:05.256000
Name: 0, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This answer is definitely the better one. I didn't know pandas had `to_timedelta` function, goode one PiRSquared

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime

#Parse your string
days, timestamp = "55 days 12:39:32.269000".split(" days ")
timestamp = timestamp[:len(timestamp)-7]

#Generate datetime object
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp,"%H:%M:%S") + datetime.timedelta(days=int(days))

#Generate a timedelta
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=t.day, hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)

#Represent in Seconds
delta.total_seconds()
```

Comment: how do I iterate this over a specific column in a pandas dataframe? thanks -- I posted my best attempt as an update to my question! it could also be made into a new column....

Comment: @GrahamStreich you should use `map`, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19798528/5496463

Comment: thank you both. I made a function and applied it with the map method, however I ran across another problem. Some of the hours are prefaced with either a '+' or '-' sign...how do I account for these...I've updated the data in my question to show you what I mean and I've updated the code to show you the function I wrote and how I am using the map method. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, looping through each value from the CSV in place of stringdate:

```
stringdate = "2 days 00:00:57.416000"
days_v_hms = string1.split('days')
hms = days_v_hms[1].split(':')
dt = datetime.timedelta(days=int(days_v_hms[0]), hours=int(hms[0]), minutes=int(hms[1]), seconds=float(hms[2]))
```

Cheers!