# Converting time in %H:%M:%S:%f of 83 days, 17:02:10.401369 python

Tags: python, django, datetime, timedelta

I need to convert time format of '83 days, 17:02:10.401369' to %H:%M:%S:%f

```
res_time = '83 days, 17:02:10.401369'
                
res_formated = datetime.strptime(res_time, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Value Error: time data '83 days, 17:02:10.401369' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'

Comment: Split the string on `,` and try with the time only.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. thanks for your suggestion. what if I want to add the 83 days to the 17:02:10.401369?

Comment: related: [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628122/10197418). Note that `pandas.to_timedelta` can readily parse the string, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611642/turn-a-string-back-into-a-datetime-timedelta).

Answer (score 0):

like @Klaus D. say, use split to use the string:

```
res_time = '83 days, 17:02:10.401369'

res_time = res_time.split(",")[1]

res_time = res_time.strip() // Delete the white space before and after the string

res_formated = datetime.strptime(res_time, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
```